# LINQ query help please, for each works?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have a problem with some code that simply can’t work in LINQ, but it does work as a simple for..each.   Any explanation and solution would be appreciated.

I have 3 classes, Users, User , UserPermissions composed as follows:

**Class Users**

```
ObservableCollection<User> GetList
```

**Class User**

```
Public int id  {get;set;}
Public string UserName  {get;set;}
Public UserPermissions Permissions {get;set;}
```

**Class UserPermissions**

```
Public Int ID {get;set;}
Public int ApplicationID {get;set;}
```

This works and returns the correct user:

```
Users users = new Users();
foreach (User u in users.GetList() )
{
    if (u.UserName==username && u.Permissions.ApplicationID == applicationId)
    {
        usr = u;
        break;
    }
}
```

The linq below 'should' do the same thing, but it doesn’t.  There are no errors returned or raised in the output window, and the musers variable simply doesn't exist after stepping over it.  I have tried being more specific in my casts and using AsQueryable.  I even tried let p=u.Permissions, using two from commands, but nothing seems to fix it.

My worry is that my other classes will suffer from this and cause issues later on as more complex queries are used.

```
var  musers = from Users.User u in UsersList
               where (u.UserName==userName) 
                       && (u.Permissions.ApplicationID == ApplicationId)
              select u.ID;
```

One more bit of information the following errors too?

var t1 = UsersList.SelectMany( u => u.Permissions);

*Error  1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Comment: `musers` won't have anything in it until you iterate it (lots of linq methods are deferred until the point you iterate the enumerable). Try `var id = musers.FirstOrDefault();`, this will return `default(T)` if the enumerable is empty. If you want to test for empty, try `if (musers.Any()) { }`.

Comment: Extension Methods?
eg: UserList.Where(x=>x.UserName == userName && x.Permissions.ApplicationID == ApplicationId).Select(x=>x);
OR 
UserList.Select(x=>x.UserName == userName && x.Permissions.ApplicationID == ApplicationId)

Comment: already tried this Alex, did copy and paste your example and same result as my code im afraid. but thanks for trying.

Comment: @AlexDenysenko The query syntax is compiled into that, although the code that you just wrote out isn't quite correct, there is no change that would come of using that syntax if it were correct.

Comment: @user1284624 Stick an `AsEnumerable` right after the list name.  Currently your "working" code sample is doing all of the filtering on the application side, the linq example is using the query provider to do it before it gets there, and that may be having an issue.  If using `AsEnumerable` works it likely means the query provider is having trouble converting the expressions into a query.  What query provider are you using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam was spot on thank you Adam.

I have seen in the debugger that 'var found=from...' showed that found is created and contains a value at the point where the linq statement is run.  However, as Adam correctly states that linq enumeration is deferred until the point you enumerate the query.  The reason it all looked fine to me was that directly under the code that worked was a for loop which triggers the enumeration for THAT linq query.  The others above it had no such enumeration so just looked as if they had failed silently!

I think the compiler was optimizing the function so that I could debug the linq query at the point it is in the code rather than where the enumeration occurs, nice trick but it completely wrong footed me! lol.  It made me think that the query itself is evaluated to some degree even if the results aren't available until you use ToList(), Count() or other enumeration function.

for example in the code below only f3 will contain anything at all, the others are just, well, nothing because they are never enumerated!

var f1 = from .....;

var f2 = from ....;

var f3 = from ....;

do lots of other stuff, even call a function

int count = f3.Count();

What is interesting is that f1, f2 are nothing even after the line runs but f3 has a value immediately after and before the enumeration (Count) takes place, so i think compiler optimization/debug is playing a part here.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

```
        var usr = users.GetList()
            .FirstOrDefault(
                p => p.UserName == username 
                    && p.Permissions.ApplicationID == applicationId);
```

Should actually do it for you. FirstOrDefault can return null, if no user has been found...

Comment: None of the suggestions so far fix the issue, although they should all work.  I should have specified that the collection is under my control and the base and all children are correctly populated.  So FirstOrDefault is not required. But thanks for you help so far.

Comment: hmmm i just noticed something:

   p => p.UserName == userName && p.Permissions.ApplicationID == applicationId

The p.UserName has linq extensions but p.Permissions.ApplicationID does not? does this have significance?

Comment: I just create a console app with exactly your code and both, your look and my FirstOrDefault work just fine as expected...
I can post the code if you want. If this doesn't work for you, something else seems to be wrong

Comment: The error below occurs when i try to SelectMany,  suggests some sort of enumerable error with Permissions object doesn't it?

var t1 = UsersList.SelectMany( u => u.Permissions);

Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\Workspace\Users\Users.cs 131 30 Users